# AKClipPlayer playing in the middle of clip

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to make audio player and instead of using AKAudioPlayer which is taking too much ram on init, i'm using AKClipPlayer like that:

```
AudioKit.engine.prepare()
let clip = AKFileClip(audioFile: self.recorderAKAudioFile!)
self.player = AKClipPlayer(clips: [clip])
try! AudioKit.engine.start()
if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
     AudioKit.output = self.player
                //set the time
    self.player?.currentTime = self.playPositionSeconds
    self.player?.play()
    runPlayerAnimations()
}
```

The problem is that audio is silent almost every time i run this code on long recording and it does not matter what play position i set. Is there a better way to play audio with specific starting time and not kill app with using all devices ram?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We've added a new audio player called [AKPlayer](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Player/AKPlayer.swift). It's in the development branch. Please give it a try. It will stream from disk by default but you can also set a buffering scheme if wanted. Looping, Fading and Reversing require buffering.

```
player.play(from: time)
```